# Detecting if a page is using Angular 2+ with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, angular

I am using Google Polymer on top of an Angular 2 app and I need a way in the Polymer JavaScript to determine if the page in running Angular 2 or not. I had read somewhere that  `if (window.ng) {}` works and it has for me up until yesterday. Now, it works in `localhost` but has stopped working on my test and production servers. Now, `window.ng` is undefined.

When I debug the Polymer JavaScript and step through it slowely, I get the following console errors:

```
(WEB_PAGE context) Lazy require of app.binding did not set the binding field
(WEB_PAGE context) Lazy require of webstore.binding did not set the binding field
(WEB_PAGE context) Lazy require of runtime.binding did not set the binding field
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Angular automatically adds an attribute `ng-version` to the root component's tag, so you can parse that attribute's value like this assuming the root component is the first child of `body`

```
const majorVersion = parseInt(document.body.children[0].getAttribute('ng-version').split('.')[0])
console.log(majorVersion >= 2);
```

Comment: I don't see an `ng-version` attribute on my body tag

Comment: That's weird. Maybe on the root component's tag?

Comment: don't see it there either. I can't find that attribute anywhere on the page

Comment: I have no idea, my angular apps have `ng-version` on the body tag.

Comment: Correction, the `ng-version` is added by angular to the root component's tag, not the body tag